# Blackberry dialog launched on PhoneListener's callInitiated method

Tags: java, blackberry, dialog, listen

Hy.

I have a situation with an UiApplication for Blackberry 5.0.0 OS that may be of interest to the communnity or with wich someone could help me.

My application implements the PhoneListener interface to be notified when an outbound call is detected on the device (callInitiated method). Upon that, the app simulates a disconnect key press to cancel the call. Then, a Dialog is launched and some action is required on the user side...

All works well when the number is dialed through the phone app, the dialog is launched, the phone app dissapears and the dialog remains on screen waiting for user action. But if the user dials through the contacts list, speed dial or numbers in web pages, the dialog appears but quickly dissapears when the phone app dissapears (after the call is artificially disconnected).

I'll be paciently awaiting for a response from someone that can shed some light on this... thanks.

Comment: What about just calling `Thread.sleep` with a few seconds before showing dialog?

Comment: That just delays the display of the dialog, with the side effect of the app taking too long to disconnect the call. :/

Comment: Then disconnect, wait a few seconds, and finally show the dialog.

Comment: No luck. Everything done with Thread.sleep just seems to delay everything, freezing the phone in the meanwhile.

Comment: Try showing your dialog as a global screen: `Ui.getUiEngine().pushGlobalScreen(yourDialog, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);`

Comment: Was just trying something like that. It seems to work, but "boolean inputRequired" must be set to UiEngine.GLOBAL_MODAL. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

The dialog must be created in another way. I was using Dialog.ask by the way.

```
Screen screen = null;
synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()){ 

    UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
    screen = new Dialog("<dialog text>", <options>, <values>, 0, Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION));
    ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_MODAL);

}
int appMethodAsked = ((Dialog) screen).getSelectedValue();
```

To note that, a key detail for this code to work is the UiEngine.GLOBAL_MODAL value passed to the pushGlobalScreen method. Without this, the same thing described as the problem will happen.